# Tradução do privilégio "usuário estabelecido"

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, localização

A descrição do privilégio "usuário estabelecido" diz:

> 750 usuário estabelecido - Você esteve fora durante algum tempo; veja a contagem de votos

No SO inglês, o privilégio é:

> 1000 established user - You've been around for a while; see vote counts

"Você esteve fora durante algum tempo" está errado. Acho que uma melhor tradução seria "Já cá está há algum tempo".

Comment: Você é português?

Comment: @bigown Sou sim, porquê?

Comment: Achar uma tradução que satisfaça tanto pt-BR quanto pt-PT, deve ser uma tarefa complicada...

Comment: @felipe.avelar "Você esteve fora" significa "You've been around" em pt-BR?

Comment: Não, a tradução está errada mesmo. Eu falo isso por causa do "Já cá está há algum tempo." em pt-BR seria algo como "Você já está aqui faz algum tempo.". Essas pequenas diferenças linguísticas que eu acho que vão ser um pouco mais complicadas de diferenciar.

Comment: @dcastro "Já cá está há algum tempo" soa muito estranho para nós brasileiros. Temos que achar outra sugestão que satisfaça todos que falam português.

Comment: @Math nao sabia.. Eu entendo "Você já está aqui faz algum tempo", como sugerido pelo felipe, mas nao sei se outros portugueses entenderiam..

Comment: @felipe.avelar Podem sugerir outras opcoes. So acho que o texto actual esta errado e devia ser mudado :)

Comment: Sim, o texto atual está completamente errado, ele está dizendo exatamente o contrário, que "você esteve fora", quando na verdade você estava por perto, ou algo do tipo.

Comment: "Já cá" soa estranho para um brasileiro. Parece "jaca".

Comment: Que tal usar "Já está conosco há algum tempo"? Foge um pouco do pé da letra, mas....

Comment: Concordo com a "resposta" invisível do bfavaretto. Qualquer uma destas opções é melhor do que nenhuma delas.

Comment: [O que significa “modificada pelo bfavaretto♦”?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1953/3117)

Comment: @Math Devia ser a resposta que eu excluí: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2667/

Comment: @bfavaretto sim, era para ser uma piada, mas não sei se ficou claro rs.. é pq vc deu um bump no tópico igual a Comunidade faz de vez em quando, só que você utilizou de um artifício para fazer isso, pois vc não é que nem a Comunidade que dá bumps sem nenhuma alteração visível, apesar de ser visível para poucos usuários oq vc fez ainda é diferente da Comunidade :)

Comment: @Math Eu não tinha entendido a piada... Mas na verdade a intenção não foi dar bump, eu postei uma resposta quando estava meio nervoso, e depois resolvi apagar :)

Comment: @bfavaretto o importante é que o problema foi resolvido

Answer (score 11):

Precisamos mesmo traduzir o primeiro trecho da descrição? Ele me parece desnecessário, nenhum outro privilégio tem algo similar, eles vão direto ao assunto. Confiram na [**lista completa de privilégios**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges).

Que tal:

> **Ver a contagem de votos**

* aproveitando a resposta do @brasofilo que observa que os outros privilégios estão no infinitivo.

Comment: É fato, na versão em Inglês também é a única que tem essa espécie de saudação. Apoiado, fora com ela!

Answer (score 5):

Acham que isto é transoceânico?

> Você já frequenta o site por um bom tempo; ver a contagem de votos.

Os outros privilégios estão no infinitivo, por isso "ver" em vez de "veja".

Answer (score 3):

Sugestão de tradução que satisfaz ambos os lados do oceano:

"Participação consistente há algum tempo; veja contagem de votos."

Answer (score 0):

"esteve fora" soa bastante estranho no contexto.

Talvez:

> 750 usuário estabelecido - Você esteve **por aqui** durante algum tempo; veja a contagem de votos

Ou:

> 750 usuário estabelecido - Você **já está aqui** durante algum tempo; veja a contagem de votos